# Updating a value - do I have to call Model.findById() and then call Model.updateOne()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a User model that contains number of points that user has. To update it, do I have to perform two queries?

First get the User document by `.findById()` to get the current points and then add the current points with X amount and then call `.updateOne()` to update the User document's points?

Comment: For updating any value in the database you should know the id or some other value of the record to update. If you already know the id of the record to update then there is no need for two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `$inc` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) and use the `.updateOne()` method to do so.

```
db.collection('users').updateOne({_id: '...'}, {$inc: {score: 100}})
```

Comment: been trying to debug it for the past hour can't get it to work. ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined``` getting this error. I'm using a ```mongoUtil.js``` class to handle routes

Comment: Could you help me figure out why? https://pastebin.com/9cUmD2w2

Comment: yeah sure, i'll check it out

Comment: This might do the trick... had to do some changes to your mongoUtils.js tho [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zLNkX4N0). Hope it helps!

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thank you soooooo much!

Comment: You're welcome! Just to add a little more, make sure you add a method or some event handling so you close the connection when you won't use it anymore or your program finishes, otherwise you may overload your mongo cluster :D